# Check to see if array item is string or xml node in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, internet-explorer-8

I have a javascript array. Some items in the array are xml nodes and some are strings, if it is a string it is always the same string. I need a cross-browser solution to identify if the item is an xml node or not, that will work in everything from IE8 to modern browsers. Initially I just compared the item against the string like so:

```
var isNode = true;
if (array[i] == "my string") {
    isNode = false;
}
```

However this caused an error in IE8 on XP if the array item was xml node. So I tried this:

```
var isNode = true;
try {
    var nodeName = array[i].context.tagName;
} catch (ex) {
    isNode = false;
}
```

This worked in IE8 but isNode always returns as false in Chrome.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, since I do not see the string in your post but maybe Regular Expression may help with something like:

```
(/([<].*[>])/gi).test('demo')              //returns false
(/([<].*[>])/gi).test('<node> </node>')    //returns true
```